# Translation in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working in a Angular project where it exists a json file located in src\assets\i18n containing translations in Swedish:

```
{
  "COMMON": {
    "BUTTON-NO-FILE": "Dokument saknas",
    "BUTTON-EDIT": "Redigera",
    "BUTTON-SAVE": "Spara",
    "BUTTON-CANCEL": "Avbryt",
    "BUTTON-OK": "Ok",
    "BUTTON-CLOSE": "Stäng",
    "ERRORS": {
      "GENERAL-TITLE": "Ett fel har inträffat",
      "401-MSG": "Testing 401 message",
      "499-MSG": "Applikationen svarar inte, försök igen senare.",
      "403-MSG": "Handlingen kan inte utföras, kontrollera din behörighet.",
      "404-MSG": "Resurserna som du försöker nå finns inte.",
      "400-MSG": "Ett fel har inträffat. Kontakta HSB om felet fortfarande kvarstår."
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have added a message for error code 401: "Testing 401 message".

Now, it is a file where the error messages in the translation json file are mapped, based on which error status it is:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageDialogService } from '@hsbweb/hsb-shared-components-module';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private messageDialogService: MessageDialogService,
    private translate: TranslateService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(request)
          .pipe(
              catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  let errorMessage = '';
                  switch (error.status) {
                    case 499:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.499-MSG');
                      break;
                    case 404:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.404-MSG');
                      break;
                    case 403:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.403-MSG');
                      break;
                    case 400:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.400-MSG');
                      break;
                    case 401:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.401-MSG');
                      break;
                    default:
                      errorMessage = this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.400-MSG');
                      break;
                  }
                  this.messageDialogService.error(
                    this.translate.instant('COMMON.ERRORS.GENERAL-TITLE'),
                    errorMessage,
                    this.translate.instant('COMMON.BUTTON-OK'));

                  return throwError(error);
              })
          );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have added my case for 401-message. But the problem I have is that it prints the string `COMMON.ERRORS.401-MSG`, instead of the value in the translation file.

So my question is if I have to do something to the json file after I have edited it? I have tried to re-compile the angular project, but that does not help either.

I'm new to Angular. How can I proceed?

Comment: Do your other translations work correctly?

Comment: @MarkS.: Yes they do.

Comment: The key is shown for two reasons. Either the key you have in your `this.translate.instant` doesn't match exactly something in your translation file or the translation file didn't load properly. Since the other translations are working, we can assume the translations are loading properly. So I would check spelling, spacing, etc. to see if it matches. Also try swapping the 401 key with one of the other keys to see if it is being requested correctly.

Comment: @MarkS: I tried to change the value of the 404 key in the translation file, but my changes was not loaded. The old value still appeard. So it must have something to do with how it's loaded when edited.

Comment: Are you sure that you're editing the correct file? Is there a different file in your project where it's getting the translations from?

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things here.

- You're passing the string literal `'COMMON.ERRORS.4xx-MSG'`
- Remove the quotes
- To access the items in json through Angular you can use the `HttpClient` to get them.

Take a look at this example for a service that you could use to retrieve json objects from a file (i haven't tested this but I recon it would do the job)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigProvider {
    public settings: AppConfig;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

    load(): Promise<any> {
        const jsonFile = `src\assets\i18n.json`;
        return this.http
            .get<AppConfig>(jsonFile)
            .pipe(
                tap(res => {
                    this.settings = res;
                })
            )
            .toPromise();
    }

    public getAppSetting(path: string) {
           return Object.keys(this.settings)
            .filter(setting => setting.includes(path))
            .map(filteredSetting => this.settings[filteredSetting]);
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the following for any assets that you want your Angular project to properly load and reference.

In your `angular.json` projects.app-name.architect.build.assets[]

```
{
 "glob": "*.json",
 "input": "src/assets/config",
 "output": "assets/config"
}
```

> **If this is too much. I'd recommend swapping the .json file for a file of constants in your projects. Then you can just import those as usual, rather than doing this whole app service. Which is slightly overkill.**

Let me know if there is anything that doesn't make sense. Cheers.